how to do react axios interceptor setup where if local storage don't have accessToken then want to clear local storage and navigate user to login?
Suppose I am creating a React project, and in that project, I want to set up Axios. For Axios setup, I am creating an Axios interceptor file where, before each API call, I am checking if this domain's local storage does not have an accessToken. In such a case, I simply want the local storage of this domain to be cleared, and the user should be navigated back to '/auth/login'. However, since this is a single-page application (SPA), I don't want to refresh the page by using window.location.reload(); or window.location.href = '/auth/login'.
simply without refreshing the page i want to navigate user back to 'auth/login'

to handle this redirection in your react project using Axios without refreshing the page, you can use React Router along with an Axios interceptor .
First make sure React Router is setup in your app for client-side routing.
Create your axios interceptor and check if accessToken is missing in locale storage.
Use React Router for navigation without a page refresh.
Example:
create your custom hook:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxiosInterceptor = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const axiosInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
      if (!token) {
        localStorage.clear();
        navigate('/auth/login');
      }
      return config;
    }, error => {
      // Handle error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    return () => {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(axiosInterceptor);
    };
  }, [navigate]);
};

Then use this hook in the components where you make API calls.
More info about react router you can find on their official website
https://reactrouter.com/en/main

is it a optimal and performant way to navigate user this way . are there other ways also or not ?
